# How to cache 2D arrays in google-apps-script?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, caching

I have been trying to cache a google sheet ("SubmissionsTable". For the first run when the cache is empty, everything works fine. However on the subsequent runs which read from the Cache, "SubmissionsTable" will only have the first row and all other rows are removed. I attached the code in case I misunderstood something.
Example :

Run 1 : Reading from file after splice `Submission Table = [[1,2,3],[a,b,c]]`

Run 2 : Reading from cache `Submission Table = [1,2,3]`

Edit : Running this code as is should reproduce the problem. If you are interested, this is the sheet the data is fetched from : [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ijO1mVZ2NasggFvvmdPGUfZkrdOZVhjkM0CbrPYFlhM/edit?usp=sharing)

```
var Cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
var SubmissionsSheetId = "1ijO1mVZ2NasggFvvmdPGUfZkrdOZVhjkM0CbrPYFlhM";
var SubmissionsTable = Cache.get('submissions');
  if (!SubmissionsTable)
  {
    SubmissionsTable = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SubmissionsSheetId).getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
    SubmissionsTable.splice(0,1);
    Cache.put('submissions',SubmissionsTable,20*60);
  }
```

Comment: It will work with anything that you can JSON.stringify() to load and then JSON.parse.() to restore.

Comment: Cache is undefined in your example

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for your help !
Yes this is just a sippet from my code not the whole thing.

Comment: It's like PropertiesService in that it save's everything as a string.

Comment: I would suggest that you always provide a [mcve] if you want to improve your chances of getting an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would seem to suggest otherwise:

```
function trycache() {
  const a =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
  let cs=CacheService.getScriptCache();
  cs.put('mykey',JSON.stringify(a));
  const b=JSON.parse(cs.get('mykey'));

  Logger.log(b[0][2]);
}

Execution log
10:28:23 AM Notice  Execution started
10:28:24 AM Info    3.0
10:28:23 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help ! Sorry for not properly checking JSON.stringify